# Convert job AX to sql server function query

Tags: sql-server-2012, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, ssms-2012, ssms-2014

In Ax i have the following job that get my correct result. Now i want to do some thing in Sql server management service using SQL SERVER.So , for each record in InventTable  we identify recursively all categories (EcoResCategory.Name) higher level and their associated parent , and feed Name field with the identified category>

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllCategoryLevelName](@ecoResCtg OBJECT , @Parent OBJECT )
RETURNS VARCHAR 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    while (
            select @Parent.Level --order by @Parent.Level asc  
            From MicrosoftDynamicsAX.dbo.EcoResCategory          AS  EcoResCategoryParent
            where EcoResCategoryParent.CategoryHierarchy         =  @ecoResCtg.CategoryHierarchy
                    AND   EcoResCategoryParent.NestedSetLeft     <= @ecoResCtg.NestedSetLeft
                    AND   EcoResCategoryParent.NestedSetRight    >= @ecoResCtg.NestedSetLeft
            order by @Parent.Level asc
           )
    BEGIN
       CASE @Parent.Level
            WHEN 1 THEN  level1 = parent.Name
            WHEN 2 THEN  level2 = parent.Name
            WHEN 3 THEN  level3 = parent.Name
            WHEN 4 THEN  level4 = parent.Name
            WHEN 5 THEN  level5 = parent.Name
       END

    END
)
```

Inside this function i don't know how to pass object parameter
Can anybody help in this regard.
Regards

Comment: Can anybody help in this regard. Regards

Comment: How should this work? You cannot return containers from T-SQL. What's the use case or underlying requirement here?

Comment: It's ok i m using table temporaire for each level